# How to I retrieve call duration when someone leaves a call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

How to I retrieve call duration when someone leaves a call?

I am trying to use `getStats()` but I am only being returned a state value.

```
console.log("this.room.getStats() ", this.room.getStats());
```

returns:

```
this.room.getStats()  
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Maybe something like

```js
const stats = await this.room.getStats();
const remoteTrackStats = kind === 'audio'
    ? stats[0].remoteAudioTrackStats[0]
    : stats[0].remoteVideoTrackStats[0]
const bytesReceived = remoteTrackStats.bytesReceived;
const timestamp = remoteTrackStats.timestamp;
```

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer but I am not getting an array back form getStats(). I am only getting a hash with state: pending in it and nothing else. I am testing locally on my development environment, maybe I need to use https instead of http.

Comment: I will accept this answer but maybe I should mention that I needed to be configured for HTTPS in my development environment.

Comment: Also, can you confirm that timestamp is actually the call duration?